# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined , javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

trying to go through a dictionary and get values and get each of the array values in it to manipluate them but get this error, at first I thought it might be because I forgot the semi-colon at the line that defines the dict but the error stays.

```
 getPieChartSeries(logsList){
   let devidedLogs = this.divideLogsByExitCode(logsList);
   console.log(devidedLogs);
   let pieChartSeries = [];
   Object.values(devidedLogs).array.forEach(element => {
     pieChartSeries.push(this.getPrecentageOfLogType(element,logsList))
   });
   console.log(pieChartSeries)
 }

 getPrecentageOfLogType(logsList,logsOfTypeList){
   let numOflogs = logsList.length
   let numOflogsOfType = logsOfTypeList.length
   let precentageOfLogType = Math.round((numOflogsOfType  / numOflogs ) * 100)

   return precentageOfLogType
 }
 getCurrentTime(){
   var d = new Date();
   return d.toLocaleString()
 }
```

devidedLogs is

```
{failedFaults: Array(0), failedProbesLogs: Array(1), failedRollbackLogs: Array(0), rollbackedLogs: Array(0), selfHealedLogs: Array(3)}failedFaults: []failedProbesLogs: [{…}]failedRollbackLogs: []rollbackedLogs: []selfHealedLogs: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]__proto__: Object
```

Comment: what's your `devidedLogs` data?

Comment: Please provide input data

Comment: {failedFaults: Array(0), failedProbesLogs: Array(1), failedRollbackLogs: Array(0), rollbackedLogs: Array(0), selfHealedLogs: Array(3)}

Comment: But you don't have ```array``` property inside your `devidedLogs` object

Comment: Each one of the values in the devidedLogs dict is an array (0 so when I go through the values of it i can do .array to each of one them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are iterating on the wrong variable.

Already **.values()** return the array, you don't have to add **.array** again after that.

So your code should be updated to the below lines:

```
getPieChartSeries(logsList){
 let devidedLogs = this.divideLogsByExitCode(logsList);
 console.log(devidedLogs);
 let pieChartSeries = [];
 Object.values(devidedLogs).forEach(element => {
 pieChartSeries.push(this.getPrecentageOfLogType(element,logsList))
 });
 console.log(pieChartSeries)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values(devidedLogs)` will return an Array of all Object values, equivalently, you can use `Object.keys(devidedLogs)` to obtain the keys or `Object.entries(devidedLogs)` for an Array of key-value tuples.

Check also the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) of the Object class :)

Comment: By fetching keys, we would again need to parse the keys and get the values in front of each key. Because as per the requirement we need the values of the logs.